# lshw -C display shows UNCLAIMED for GT840M graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've tried everyway to install drivers for NVIDIA and get it working but my laptop still insist on using Intel Haswell integrated GPU.

Here's a what I've tried so far:

First I've tried to install latest drivers from graphics-driers PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```

I was hoping that it could get my graphics card to work but it didn't.

Then I downloaded `.run` file from offical nVidia website but this installer gives me **"The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!"** error. Still don't know why it gives me such error.

Last thing I tried was after installing nvidia-367:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
sudo prime-select nvidia
reboot
```

As you can guess, it didn't work either. `sudo lshw -C display` command gives me following output:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:43 memory:b5000000-b53fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:6000(size=64)
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 840M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and my graphics card is nVidia GT 840M

Comment: You probably need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: OMFG, thanks man it worked like a magic. If I was in the same country with you I'd make a car ride in this very night to your home and hug till you poop. Thanks again! (not gay)

Comment: Well, I'm working with a similar issue and trying to *blacklist* the wrong driver, may be this may help you if the issue still stands:
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/Installation_Guide/rescuemode_drivers-blacklisting.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Secure Boot does not let the `nvidia` module load.

Disable Secure boot in BIOS and it should be solved.

You can see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/762254/167850) for more information.

Comment: That didn't solve it for me unfortunately. Already have it disabled but still have it unclaimed.

Comment: Do you mind adding [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049021/sudo-lshw-c-display-shows-unclaimed-for-both-intel-and-nvidia-graphics-lsmod#comment1727116_1049021) in this answer?

Answer (score 1):

`display UNCLAIMED` can also mean a hardware problem. Especially if the problems started without any software updates.