# resolution in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, display, display-resolution

The default resolution doesn't fit my screen. **It works perfectly in the recovery mode** but in the normal boot I can only get a big resolution. It sais `The CRTC 381 is not to be found`.

I would like to have a resolution of 1024x768 61Hz.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video

*-display UNCLAIMED
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe400000-fe7fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:dc00(size=8)
```

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

### What I tried

- I had this problem also with Ubuntu 12.04. There the solution was to change the Xorg.conf file, but such file is missing.
- Tried using `xrandr` but doesn't seem to work.

---

I hope sombody can help so I don't have to start in the recovery mode each time.

Greetings

Comment: Mind you in the recovery mode it's all great...right resolution everything works!

Comment: What exactly did you try with `xrandr`? Maybe you can use `arandr` instead, which is a visual front end for `xrandr` and pretty simple to use.

Comment: I tried to implement a mode fore the above mentiond resolution. I doesn't work. arandr doesn't work either because it uses xrandr. Thanks for your trouble. I need sombody that knows a lot about making costum modes in the configuration. Thats why i think it works in the recoverymode boot...because i think than something is switched of by GRUB....

Answer (score 0):

To give appropriate advice facts are neccessary, results of commands are needed. 
Saying "it doesn't work" makes sense to you but we can't see what you are seeing. 
I'm sure you understand what I mean.
The output of **xrandr** is the usual starting point for us to get an understanding of your configuration. If the command gives an error, that too maybe vital information.

Comment: I see what you mean ... i get back with some more info later...

Comment: the info is in the answer above

Comment: @smitje: I found a similar question/answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/819312/lshw-c-display-shows-unclaimed-for-gt840m-graphics-card
I suggests that Secure Boot is the culprit. Please check it out...

Comment: how do i disable the secure boot? and isn't it dangerous?

Comment: You disable Secure Boot in BIOS. For more info please read: `https://neosmart.net/wiki/disabling-secure-boot/`. I don't consider it dangerous. In fact I was forced to turn it off before I was able to create a properly working dual-boot machine.

Comment: Hi willem i wanted to show you what i have done but i can't send you pictures...because i don't have enough credits on this forum. It toke me some time to make the draft with the pictures so i am really not willing to make links now.....so maybe later....

Comment: What i forgot to say is that i couldn't find the mentuoned option in my BIOS

Comment: Hi i tried to look in my bios an didn't find an option to disable the secure boot option.
![Boot settings][1] 
![security settings][2]


  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HuqK.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWJ5I.jpg

Comment: In the comment above you can see the pictures....

Comment: Oh by the way....my windows is windows 7 not 8 .  I read somewhere that secure boot is a feature of windows 8 .

Comment: Your bios is from 2009, Secure Boot was not available then. So that is not the issue. That leaves you with the display driver software. I found a similar posting that could be helpfull: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=202637.  Please know I am on holiday for the next 6 week, so I will not be online very often.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info.... same for me last weeks of May... have a nice trip! I can work with the recovery mode but ill keep on posting some new discoveries..maybe

Comment: **Ican't find**  the mentioned file fglrx-core.conf **what I do find is:**         '      markward@markward-desktop:/etc/modprobe.d$ dir'
'     alsa-base.conf      blacklist-modem.conf  iwlwifi.conf'
        ' blacklist-ath_pci.conf     blacklist-oss.conf   libpisock9.conf'
        'blacklist.conf      blacklist-rare-network.conf  mlx4.conf'
         'blacklist-firewire.conf     blacklist-watchdog.conf  vmwgfx-fbdev.conf'
'blacklist-framebuffer.conf  fbdev-blacklist.conf'

Answer (score 0):

I found it on this forum...

```
markward@markward-desktop:~$ cvt 640 480 60
    # 640x480 59.38 Hz (CVT 0.31M3) hsync: 29.69 kHz; pclk: 23.75 MHz
    Modeline "640x480_60.00"   23.75  640 664 720 800  480 483 487 500 hsync +vsync

markward@markward-desktop:~$  xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1024x768
    xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
    warning: output LVDS not found; ignoring

markward@markward-desktop:~$  xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
warning: output VGA1 not found; ignoring


markward@markward-desktop:~$  xrandr --addmode S-video 1024x768
    xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
    xrandr: cannot find output "S-video"
```

- and also this is the error mesage i get starting up... it means non
  of the selected modi are compatible with the possible modi
- I don't get this message if I start up in the recovery mode

  ```
  geen van de geselecteerde modi waren compatibel met de mogelijke modi: Proberen modi voor CRTC 379 
  CRTC 379: uitproberen modus 640x480@73Hz met uitvoer op 1024x768@61Hz (ronde 0) 
  CRTC 379: uitproberen modus 640x480@73Hz met uitvoer op 1024x768@61Hz (ronde 1)
  ```

This is the only resolution option available

```
    markward@markward-desktop:~$ xrandr 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default 
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480 
    default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm 
   640x480        73.0*
```

- I also found this

  ```
   lspci|grep -i vga
   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
  ```
- and this

  ```
    cvt -v 1024 678 60
    Warning: Aspect Ratio is not CVT standard.
    # 1024x678 59.81 Hz (CVT) hsync: 42.17 kHz; pclk: 56.00 MHz
    Modeline "1024x678_60.00"   56.00  1024 1072 1176 1328  678 681 691 705 -hsync +vsync
  ```

Answer (score 0):

- Ican't find the mentioned file fglrx-core.conf
- What I do find in /etc/modprobe.d is:

  ```
   markward@markward-desktop:/etc/modprobe.d$ dir
   alsa-base.conf             blacklist-modem.conf         iwlwifi.conf
   blacklist-ath_pci.conf     blacklist-oss.conf           libpisock9.conf
   blacklist.conf             blacklist-rare-network.conf  mlx4.conf
   blacklist-firewire.conf    blacklist-watchdog.conf      vmwgfx-fbdev.conf
   blacklist-framebuffer.conf fbdev-blacklist.conf
  ```