# sudo lshw -C display shows UNCLAIMED for both Intel and Nvidia graphics. lsmod | grep nouveau showing nouveau drivers installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04, nouveau

ph97@ph97-XPS-15-9560:~$ sudo lshw -C display

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
description: 3D controller
product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
*-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

~$ lsmod | grep nouveau

```
nouveau              1716224  0
ttm                   106496  1 nouveau
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    24576  7   
nouveau,dell_smbios_wmi
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 nouveau,i915
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 nouveau,i915
drm                   401408  4 nouveau,i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
video                  40960  4 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,nouveau,i915
```

I have already blacklisted Nouveau drivers with this method

cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

I have also regenerate initramfs and rebooted

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

nvidia-smi shows

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

sudo apt install nvidia-390 shows

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-390 is already the newest version (390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Besides that my nvdia x server does not launch when I click it.

I am stuck trying to install the nvidia drivers for a few days searching for possible solutions. I am a newbie trying to install cuda and cudnn for starting machine learning. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: I have changed  UEFI secure boot to OFF. However this leads to another issue when booting into Ubuntu 18.04 . This resulted in errors on booting showing PCIE Bus Error : severity = Corrected, type=Data Link Layer id=00e0(Transmitter ID)..... Replay timer timeout

Comment: It was fine again when I enabled back UEFI secure boot.

Comment: Nvidia driver won't work with Secure Boot enabled.

Comment: Thanks secure boot is one of the problems. I have managed to get the Nvidia prime driver working. I have replaced the nomodeset in grub with nouveau.modeset=0. THE nomodeset seemed to be intefering with the Nvidia graphics driver.

Comment: That is correct. `nomodeset` disables all drivers. You need to remove it after you install drivers. `nouveau.modeset=0` is not needed either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lshw -C display shows UNCLAIMED for GT840M graphics card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819312/lshw-c-display-shows-unclaimed-for-gt840m-graphics-card)