# Ubuntu 16.04 is not detecting monitor connected via HDMI cable

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, hdmi, gpu-driver, nvidia-geforce

I am using an **Acer Predator Helios 300** Core i7 7th Gen - G3-572 Gaming Laptop(having Nvidia Geforce 1050Ti graphics card). It originally comes with Windows 10 and I made it dual boot and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. When I am connecting a monitor to the laptop via HDMI cable, it failed to detect it. When I am doing the same while using Windows 10, it is successfully detecting it. I have tried every solution I found online but unable to solve the issue. Whenever I am installing Nvidia driver, I got stuck in an infinite login loop, unable to solve it either.

Ubuntu Specifications:

- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8
- Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
- OS type: 64 bit

From above specs, it's clearly visible that Nvidia driver is not Installed. I would really appreciate someone's help/guidance on the same. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** : Output of `sudo lshw -C display`

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff   *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 was a pain to get any Nvidia drivers working. Next week Ubuntu 20.04 is being released and I'd recommend Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04.

Considering you have a decent and newer Nvidia card. This site helped me get Nvidia working a few years ago. Do all your updates and upgrades first. Maybe even `do-release-upgrade` and move up to 18.04.

I recommend proprietary drivers for Nvidia cards, skip the open source.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/

[Unable to install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070630/unable-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-1)

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Found this based on lshw output from: [lshw -C display shows UNCLAIMED for GT840M graphics card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819312/lshw-c-display-shows-unclaimed-for-gt840m-graphics-card)

Secure Boot does not let the nvidia module load.

Disable Secure boot in BIOS and it should be solved.

You can see this question for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was previously using ubuntu 18.04 and was able to successfully installed the NVIDIA driver, but due to a project, I switched back to 16.04.

Comment: Either manually install the latest 16.04 kernel v4.15.x or install HWE      sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04        Also apt remove --purge nvidia-*     all nvidia driver  and   apt autoremove  to clean up system. Reboot and try doing a TTY install instead of the GUI install.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Post your output to this command     `sudo lshw -C display`

Comment: I added the output as per your request.

Comment: This will show all Nvidia installed packages `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia` and this should have not output since you are running Nvidia proprietary drivers `lsmod | grep nouveau`  [https://askubuntu.com/questions/271613/am-i-using-the-nouveau-driver-or-the-proprietary-nvidia-driver]

Comment: And you can confirm driver version with this `nvidia-smi` and then you can check Nvidia site if you want to try a newer or older driver. Hopefully that will help find a driver that works best for you.